# 3D mesh from X Y Z data

Tags: 3d, mesh

I have a set of data in X Y Z format. I am interested in drawing a mesh on the outer surface of this data. Any algorithm or suggestions will be highly appreciated. (no opengl)

Thank you and have a great weekend.

Comment: Use Delaunay Triangulation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492435/Delaunay-Triangulation-For-Fast-Mesh-Generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [marching cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) will be a good choice in your situation, it input a set of vertices as 3d scalars and outputs a surface mesh
if you know that the vertices already represents the outer shell of a surface(No vertices inside) i recommend you use [Poisson reconstruction](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version5.71/)